# Can a B tree have more solutions?

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, b-tree

I have this values

```
10,15,20,25,30,33,38,40,43,45,50
```

and then I insert 34

I tried 2 generators 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/learneroo/visual-algorithms/BTree.html 
http://ysangkok.github.io/js-clrs-btree/btree.html
and they gave me different results
[image]
[image]

On paper I tried to create the tree inserting those consecutive values 1 by1 and get a totally different result.

If the elements were in random order would the result be the same?

My result is this
[image]

The problem is when on the right I have 38|40|45 and I add 50 I have to put 40 a level higher but in the internet generators they also put 33 a level down and I don't see why

Comment: Yes and no, the first sketch you showed is clearly a **balanced BTree**, the second is essentially the same with a slight different representation. You can google for balanced trees. As an exercise try to build a BTree from an ordered input stream (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100) and then try to input it to a balanced algorithm.

Comment: @Frankie_C that is what I did in my question but with different ordered values

Comment: Sorry I haven't noted that your input is ordered. Anyway so you should have got a tree that has a linear layout like a straight line with a depth equal to the number of input elements. The formation of an unbalanced tree depends on the relation between input elements. A balanced algorithm for each adding or deletion balance the tree, moving the head to balance the number of branches trying to make them of same depth.

Comment: @Frankie_C I edited my question,adding 50 and then 34 seems to be the problem because at that point the generators put 33 a level down for some reason

Comment: The problem with your tree is that `43` is to the left of `40`. So your tree is not valid.

Comment: @user3386109 I edited,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a B tree have more solutions?

I think you're asking whether there can be more than one one way to store a given set of keys in a b-tree, but you have already answered that yourself.  Both of the generated examples you present contain the same keys and are valid 1-3 b-trees.  The first is also a valid 1-2 b-tree.  With the correction, your attempt is also a valid 1-3 b-tree.

Note well that there are different flavors of b-tree, based on how many keys the internal nodes are permitted to contain, and also that even binary trees, with which you may be more familiar, afford many different structures for the same set of two or more keys.

> If the elements were in random order would the result be the same?

Very likely so, yes, but that's not a question of the b-tree form and structure, but rather about the implementation of the software used to construct and maintain it.

You seem confused that

> in the internet generators they also put 33 a level down and I don't see why

, but we can only speculate about the implementation of the software supporting those trees.  It's unlikely that anyone here can tell you with certainty why they produce the particular b-tree forms they do, but those forms are valid, and so, now, is yours.

Comment: Here https://image.prntscr.com/image/xB5DNIM3RfGwXLipjIgx9A.png it says that it split the tree in case if the leaves become full but why it didnt't split it when is  full? For what is this precaution ? I am so scared about the best solution because my teacher would just say that is bad implemented and will not mark my answer

Comment: @CiolteAlin, I don't see your image saying that.  In any case, you still seem to be conflating b-tree *form* with the *procedures* used to construct and maintain b-tree structure.  There are multiple variations on b-trees, starting with the bounds on the number of keys per node, and there are multiple variations on the algorithms for maintaining them.  If you mean to ask about a particular set of b-tree algorithms, then you should present those in your question.  At this point, that would be most appropriate as a separate question.

Comment: So as a conclusion my B tree is correct if there are no other factors.Thanks